# how can i use javascript variable value in asp.net button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Given

```
<asp:Label ID="lbldistance" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

I am assigning it the value with:

```
var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
document.getElementById('<%=lbldistance.ClientID%>').innerHTML=distance;
```

I want to assign lbldistance value in textbox

```
protected void btnValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtJSValue.Text = lbldistance.Text;
}
```

but when i click the btnValue, lbldistance value disappears and i don't see the value in the TextBox..

Comment: Where are you setting the value of lbldistance?

Comment: Use an HiddenField to store and get back your value to the server. HiddenField are rendered as html input with type="hidden"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot do that with a label. In ASP.NET state is kept in `ViewState` across postback. An ASP.NET `<asp:Label>` is rendered into an HTML `span` and a `span` does not have `ViewState`. Therefore, when you change the `innerHTML` of the label, you are actually changing the `innertHTML` of the `span` tag. Once you press the button, the page is posted to the server where the `Label` is constructed and it is constructed with the initial text, NOT the one you think it should since it was changed for a `span`. This (not keeping `ViewState` for a label), I think, is done for a good reason:

> An HTML label should display something to the user and it is not meant to be changed by the user so there is no point in keeping the state across postback.

To accomplish what you want, use a hidden field like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

Your javascript:

```
var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
// Assign distance to your label so it shows on the page
document.getElementById('<%=lbldistance.ClientID%>').innerHTML=distance;

// Assing distance to hidden field so you can get it on the server side
document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>').value = distance;
```

Here is how to get the value on the server side:

```
 txtJSValue.Text = this.HiddenField1.Value;
```

---

I am not sure why you are going all the way to the server to change the `Text` of the `txtJSValue` textbox. You can do that easily on the browser side the same as you are setting the label:

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtJSValue.ClientID%>').value = distance;
```

Comment: thanks.. it worked. but when i click the button the page get refreshed and value of label disappeared.

Comment: Did you read my answer carefully? The label is recreated on the server side when you hit the button because it will perform a postback to the server. So if you want it to have the new text, you need to set the text of the label from the hidden field as well. Like this: `if (Page.IsPostBack) { this.Label1.Text = this.HiddenField1.Value; }`. Make sure to read an article on post backs and view state so you understand it if you are going to be doing web development.

Comment: Now i read the answer and understood why its happing. Thanks for taking my question and for the suggestions.